# discord.py BS4 selecting second div with same class name

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, discord, discord.py

I have the following (simplified) html code:

```
<div class="container">
*other html*
</div>
<div class="container">
*html i need*
</div>
```

How can i get the info of the 2nd div?

Comment: `soup.find_all('div', class_='container')[1]` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I added it to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `find_all()` function of BeautifulSoup, you get a List of the Elements in HTML matching your criteria. See: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all

So you can find the second element by calling:

```
soup.find_all('div', class_='container')[1]
```